# Efficiently generating a list of random nonrepeating numbers in Java

Tags: java, random

I need to generate a list of non repeating random numbers between 0 and 1000 as efficiently as possible in Java. I only have 2 ideas right now and would like to know if there are any other better ideas and if not which I the following ideas should I use?

1. - generate a random number r between 0 and 1000 and add it to another array called randomArray[r] at index r
   - generate another random number and check if randomArray[r] isn't already storing a previously generated random number
   - keep going until I'm done
2. - generate an array and fill its element with its index
   - shuffle it like crazy(also, how can I do this efficiently?)
   - use the elements value in the array starting from the beginning.

Thanks!

Comment: Gee, I don't recall seeing this question already today, and it's near midnight!  A new record!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.util.Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method shuffle a List with equal likelihood. create a List and add value from 0 to 1000. Then use this method to shuffly the List.

```
List l = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    l.add(i);

Collections.shuffle(l);
```

Now the list contains the shuffled values.

Comment: Suggested Edit: `new ArrayList(1001);`

Comment: why 1001 and not 1000?

Comment: @QuinnLiu becuase from 0 to 1000 there is 1001 numbers :p

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)).

A regular `HashSet<Integer>` stores a set of `Integer`s efficiently: placing a new number and checking if a number is already present is done in constant time (when storing the numbers in an array, as you mentioned, these lookups take linear time to check).

Now, since you say you want a list of numbers, we use a `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` which has all the properties of the regular `HashSet<Integer>`, and also garantees that if you loop over the elements, you will always iterate through them in the same order.

The code would look something like this:

```
Set<Integer> randomNumberList = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

int r;

// Make sure the number is not present in the list, and then add it:
do {
  r = ... // Generate your next random number
} while( randomNumberList.contains(r) );

// At this point, we know r is not in the list, so add it:
randomNumberList.add(r);

// Do the previous as many times as you want.

// Now, to iterate over the list:
for(Integer number : randomNumberList) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Note that the `do`-`while` loop is necessary if you want to make sure you actually add a number to the list.